# Swift PKPass eror 'The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid'

Tags: swift, wallet

I'm creating a `Ticket` from my server and passing it into my ios app but I keep getting this error when I try to pass the JSON data into the `PKPass` model.

`Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.`

In my server it says that the ticket was created successfully and but I still get this error in Xcode. Am I decoding the data wrong? How can I create the `PKPass` using the JSON Response?

**Server Side code:**

```
exports.createTicket = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

const passName = "Event"

try {
  const examplePass = await createPass({
      model: "./models/Event",
      certificates: {
          wwdr: "./models/certs/wwdrc.pem",
          signerCert: "./models/certs/signerCert.pem",
          signerKey: {
              keyFile: "./models/certs/signerKey.pem",
              passphrase: "54321"
          }
      },
      overrides: {
          // keys to be added or overridden
          serialNumber: "AAGH44625236dddaffbda"
      }
  });

  examplePass.barcode("36478105430"); // Random value

// Generate the stream, which gets returned through a Promise
const stream = examplePass.generate();

res.set({
  "Content-Type": "application/vnd.apple.pkpass",
  "Content-disposition": `attachment; filename=${passName}.pkpass`
});

stream.pipe(res);

console.log("Successfully created ticket", stream)
} catch (err) {
console.log("There was an error", err)

    res.set({
        "Content-type": "text/html",
    });

    res.send(err.message);
 }
 });
```

**IOS Side:**

```
AF.request(URLString, method: .post, parameters: requestData).responseString { response in

        guard let data = response.data as? Data else { return }

        do {
            let pass = try PKPass(data: data)
            print(pass)
        } catch {
            print("Error", error)
        }


    }
```

**pass.json**

```
{
"formatVersion": 1,
"passTypeIdentifier": "pass.com.CodyHost.Finder-Dev",
"teamIdentifier": "L9C6U8UKPB",
"organizationName": "Finder",
"description": "Rolling loud new york 2020",
"eventTicket": {}
}
```

**Signature:**

`MMKABgkqwoZIwobDtw0BBwLCoMKAMMKAAgEBMQswCQYFKw4DAhoFADDCgAYJKsKGSMKGw7cNAQcBAADCoMKCCkkwwoIEIzDCggMLwqADAgECAgEZMA0GCSrChkjChsO3DQEBBQUAMGIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQKEwpBcHBsZSBJbmMuMSYwJAYDVQQLEx1BcHBsZSBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eTEWMBQGA1UEAxMNQXBwbGUgUm9vdCBDQTAeFw0wODAyMTQxODU2MzVaFw0xNjAyMTQxODU2MzVaMMKBwpYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMRMwEQYDVQQKDApBcHBsZSBJbmMuMSwwKgYDVQQLDCNBcHBsZSBXb3JsZHdpZGUgRGV2ZWxvcGVyIFJlbGF0aW9uczFEMEIGA1UEAww7QXBwbGUgV29ybGR3aWRlIERldmVsb3BlciBSZWxhdGlvbnMgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwwoIBIjANBgkqwoZIwobDtw0BAQEFAAPCggEPADDCggEKAsKCAQEAw4o4VMKmw4tWwqrDiCQ5SMOpwozDrsOsX8K4fybCkcK8NFN6w458Y8KAYXdkXsKlByPCtjnDvlAtFVZYcC1+w4Ruw4FKwoU+L8Oww57ChBrCoVfDicKvexjDv2rDuhUSSRUIGcKswqrDmyoyw63ClmNoUhU9wozCisOswr9rGMKVw6ADwqwBfcKXBWfDjg7ChcKVN2rDrQnCtsKuZ8ONUWTCn8OGXMORwrxXbmc1woB2NsKkwofCgW44wo/DmCsVTnslw5hawr9OwoPDgcKNw5LCk8OVGnHCtWDCnMKdM05Vw7kSWAzChsK4Fg3DgcOld0XCjVBIwrorLcOkwpTChcOhw6jDhMKdw4ZowqXCsMKjw7xnfnDCugJZS3dCwpE5wrnDtcONw6FMw6/DgDtIwozCpsOlIV3DvWpqwrvCpxY1YMOSw6bCrcOzRinDicOow4PCi8OpecOAamFnFcKyw7DDvcOlaMK8Yl9uw4/CmcOdw68bY8O+wpJlwqsCAwEAAcKjwoHCrjDCgcKrMA4GA1UdDwEBw78EBAMCAcKGMA8GA1UdEwEBw78EBTADAQHDvzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUwognFwnCqcK2GGDCi8Osw6vCusO2R1nDhVJUwqPCtzAfBgNVHSMEGDAWwoAUK8OQaUfClHYJw77DtGvCjS5AwqbDt0dNfwheMDYGA1UdHwQvMC0wK8KgKcKgJ8KGJWh0dHA6Ly93d3cuYXBwbGUuY29tL2FwcGxlY2Evcm9vdC5jcmwwEAYKKsKGSMKGw7djZAYCAQQCBQAwDQYJKsKGSMKGw7cNAQEFBQADwoIBAQDDmjIAwpbDhVTClMOTO8KCN2Z9LmjDlcODw4bCuMOLJsKMSMKQw48TJGpGwo5jw5TDsMOQEwbDncOYw4TDgTcVw7IzEzkmLcOOLlVAw6MLA8Kvw7oSw4LDpw0hwrjDlcKAw4/CrCgvw44twrNOwq/ChhkEw4bDqVDDnUwpRxAjw7xswrsbwphrSMKJw6Fbwp3DnkbDmzXChTXDrz7DkMOiWEs4w7TDrXVaH1xwHVY5EsOlw6ENEcOkwoklBsK9w5XCtBXCjl7DkFnCl8KQw6lLwoHDosOfGMKvRHQeGcKgOkfDjMKRHTrDqyNaw77CpS3Cl8O3e8K7w5bCh0ZCwoXDq1I9JsKyY8KowrTCscOKwo/DtMOMw6LCs8OIR8Ogwr/CmlnCg8O6w5rCmFMqwoLDtXxlLsKVw5kzXcO1w61lw4wxN8OFWgTDqGvDocOnwogDSnXCnsKbKMOLSkDCiGVDdcOdw4s6JSPDhcKeV8O4LsOOw5LCqcKSXnMuLyV1FTDCggYeMMKCBQbCoAMCAQICCHQQwpvDpcKEfzvChDANBgkqwoZIwobDtw0BAQUFADDCgcKWMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECgwKQXBwbGUgSW5jLjEsMCoGA1UECwwjQXBwbGUgV29ybGR3aWRlIERldmVsb3BlciBSZWxhdGlvbnMxRDBCBgNVBAMMO0FwcGxlIFdvcmxkd2lkZSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgUmVsYXRpb25zIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5MB4XDTE1MDcyMTIxNTIyNVoXDTE2MDcyMDIxNTIyNVowwoHDgDEuMCwGCgnCkibCicKTw7IsZAEBDB5wYXNzLmNvbS5hcHBsZS5kZXZwdWJzLmV4YW1wbGUxNTAzBgNVBAMMLFBhc3MgVHlwZSBJRDogcGFzcy5jb20uYXBwbGUuZGV2cHVicy5leGFtcGxlMRMwEQYDVQQLDApBOTNBNUNNMjc4MTUwMwYDVQQKDCxBcHBsZSBJbmMuIC0gRGV2ZWxvcGVyIFB1YmxpY2F0aW9ucyBTdGFuZGFyZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMwwoIBIjANBgkqwoZIwobDtw0BAQEFAAPCggEPADDCggEKAsKCAQEAw4DDpA/DmUgswoA0woggwrPDviQxYcObC3bChDRlwrxuC8K9w7hTUwLCpcO1AxpRJh/ChHdDFsKcasKTcsOKaQhew6PDn8KxM8Kjw45QIcKow5/ChH1Vw7vDi2Y2wo7DkjfDmRLDkUNSw5jCjMK1wofDoXteMcKwwqXDjivCkMOyw4FbTsKmwrzDmsKCw5oVdGnCpg3DiBdhw7RJw4XDhUp+wrtYwrXCg8KcwrPCi8OxUGJKwrkqHh8hbsKFw50NMsOvw5RWwqHDmAVGw7kFATFfL10jAXPClXjCm8KDwqZ0w6rCvcOZPsOIdMKGCsKJBsOKH8Kaw7bCg8OUH8OSf0zDjsK3ecO3wpfCgRU/J0U2PVDCuGLDkC3DhsOCwo/DiirDssOiwqLDokkrwql4wrhTworDmiRaw57Cn0DCqGA0T8K4wpDCokrDsSwbw5Ixw5vCo8OnwrXDjsKXWDUqXcObXcKlFcKWwotzWVzDsVQzw51cwofDvhRxwqBbwqUCAwEAAcKjwoICQjDCggI+MD0GCCsGAQUFBwEBBDEwLzAtBggrBgEFBQcwAcKGIWh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmFwcGxlLmNvbS9vY3NwLXd3ZHIwMzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUbC5Twr7CksOaDcKUw6/CtmUaPsKUwr5ZdsO/wofCtTAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMB8GA1UdIwQYMBbCgBTCiCcXCcKpwrYYYMKLw6zDq8K6w7ZHWcOFUlTCo8K3MMKCAQ8GA1UdIATCggEGMMKCAQIwwoHDvwYJKsKGSMKGw7djZAUBMMKBw7EwKQYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHWh0dHA6Ly93d3cuYXBwbGUuY29tL2FwcGxlY2EvMMKBw4MGCCsGAQUFBwICMMKBwrYMwoHCs1JlbGlhbmNlIG9uIHRoaXMgY2VydGlmaWNhdGUgYnkgYW55IHBhcnR5IGFzc3VtZXMgYWNjZXB0YW5jZSBvZiB0aGUgdGhlbiBhcHBsaWNhYmxlIHN0YW5kYXJkIHRlcm1zIGFuZCBjb25kaXRpb25zIG9mIHVzZSwgY2VydGlmaWNhdGUgcG9saWN5IGFuZCBjZXJ0aWZpY2F0aW9uIHByYWN0aWNlIHN0YXRlbWVudHMuMDAGA1UdHwQpMCcwJcKgI8KgIcKGH2h0dHA6Ly9jcmwuYXBwbGUuY29tL3d3ZHJjYS5jcmwwCwYDVR0PBAQDAgfCgDAeBgNVHSUEFzAVBggrBgEFBQcDAgYJKsKGSMKGw7djZAQOMBAGCirChkjChsO3Y2QGAwIEAgUAMC4GCirChkjChsO3Y2QGARAEIAwecGFzcy5jb20uYXBwbGUuZGV2cHVicy5leGFtcGxlMA0GCSrChkjChsO3DQEBBQUAA8KCAQEAPcOgw5ERJMOGNWzDlcO6HFMCCmkuwoUAw7Yxw5www5bCsMKpwp7DrMKow5BFOSzCjMKNU8ONFzc1XMOnw5N8wr/DlgEqa8Kkw7LDh3vCu8KOwp3DqFhiD3pVH2RCw6rChhbDrE0YHC8iwqHDswXDj3vDh8OsQhXDn8OAXSYkwonDmcK3wqjCu8OldsKswpNIwrHDgcO2w516w7V0BWzDvsKsw5AQw58xw7PDvcO4AcK3dsKwwoN+MsOtwqTCs8Oxw74zw7AlwoEvw6BAwqLDqy/CvsOpEg1tfzjCoAV4wrUsw68HO8OLwprDisK+QsKswrJkw4fDt8KbM8KdYMK6wonCvsOpVMKIAzzDpcOHwovDo8K6LsKSw5gzcEjCgsKqwpHCgFU/CUIVwqZhwpDCn3lqXmIgwqzDnsKyI8KCw6nCuWbCjcOawpV4FnnCvsO/wpFww5QbNVDDkz3CrMKWdcKrwopZwrzCuBXCvAjDlSDCgy/DswMmcxTChMONw6QFwpPCh8OmwozCvzHCggIqMMKCAiYCAQEwwoHCozDCgcKWMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECgwKQXBwbGUgSW5jLjEsMCoGA1UECwwjQXBwbGUgV29ybGR3aWRlIERldmVsb3BlciBSZWxhdGlvbnMxRDBCBgNVBAMMO0FwcGxlIFdvcmxkd2lkZSBEZXZlbG9wZXIgUmVsYXRpb25zIENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5Agh0EMKbw6XChH87woQwCQYFKw4DAhoFAMKgXTAYBgkqwoZIwobDtw0BCQMxCwYJKsKGSMKGw7cNAQcBMBwGCSrChkjChsO3DQEJBTEPFw0xNTA3MjMxODM0NDJaMCMGCSrChkjChsO3DQEJBDEWBBTCs8KcfcKfCsKtw4BOWMOEw6InwpvDt8O0HMOFNEENMA0GCSrChkjChsO3DQEBAQUABMKCAQBRKx/DtsO1RBvDocKKNMOgX8Oow7Uzb0XDsEjDlH3DhMOjdVnDpUVCXngww4BTwqshI8O6SsKIwrbDpcOQwpHChT3Dt8KKwrnDpx9tP1HCgMKMwq52EkxEwpbDgXbDgcOsAkQHS0VLw5gCw4lOwqIpw5ZxYsO4PMONw5kKwrXDpXjCtsKBw70qWS8GbMKdMsK4FsKNwrlVw6JUw7Jiw67DnMKCwqrCtMKRB8KjDwcIbXfCjl89CwbDqcKnwqfCrEkyccKGw7RGTGHCm8OxwpB2UMOYN8OmwqA4w5YQwrwLOWx1w5zDqGfDm8OOw5ULw5fCmhrDggDDiCHCknjDhDQOKSgBwogdV0PDosO6BcOiOinCpTxwwpc6wrfCt8ORIcOfCXzDkFVcWV1cRW7CoDvDmBDDusKvw7DClRlmw7RSTsKHwp3ChifDhMK6wpBBb8KgdsKSw6AWwoBmSwwsw65vwq7Cv8KXdBxKw6Yhw74mEcOAHMOEw5QDAAAAAAAA`

Comment: If you try to manually add your pass to the phone, or double click it and open it with the pass viewer on a Mac, what does the console log say?  Three main reasons - certificate/signing/manifest errors; missing mandatory files (E.g. icon.png); or invalid/missing values in pass.json.  The log will tell you why the pass is being rejected.

Comment: @PassKit I'm getting this error `The passTypeIdentifier or teamIdentifier provided may not match your certificate, or the certificate trust chain could not be verified.` when I dig a little deeper

Comment: Can you post your pass.json and base64 signature.

Comment: I have posted my pass.json file in the updated question but I don't know what you mean by base64 signature. I don't have this (at least I don't think) where would this be located? @PassKit

Comment: The signature is an essential file that sits in the .pkpass bundle.  Rename your .pkpass bundle to .zip, unzip it and there should be a signature file inside.  You will need to base64 encode it to be able to post it as text here.  Your pass.json looks ok but once this signing issue is fixed, you’ll have another problem because it needs at least one field in the eventTicket object.

Comment: Also check that your wwdr.pem is the latest certificate - Apple changed this several years ago.

Comment: @PassKit I base64 encoded the signature and updated the question.

Comment: I downloaded the latest wwdr.pem from Apple's website. @PassKit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your signature and you pass.json,  your pass is failing to load because the certificate that has been used to create the signature is:

- PassTypeId: pass.com.apple.devpubs.example
- TeamName: A93A5CM278

This doesn't match the `passTypeIdentifier` and `teamName` you have in your `pass.json`.

Replace `./models/certs/signerCert.pem` and `./models/certs/signerKey.pem` with the correct certificate and key for your PassTypeId Certificate and you should get past this error.

Any pass compiled with the `pass.json` above still will not load, but for a different reason.  The `eventTicket` object cannot be empty.