# Swift pass json response into PKPass Object

Tags: swift, wallet

I'm creating a `PKPass` from my firebase server and trying to send it to my IOS application so the user can add it to their wallet but I'm unsure about how to convert the JSON response data that I receive in my IOS app to the necessary `PKPass` Object.

**JSON Response:**

```
{"Content-Length":"1093412","function-execution-id":"xx84qotfonme","Date":"Wed, 29 Apr 2020 00:44:00 GMT","Content-Disposition":"attachment; filename=Event.pkpass","Server":"Google Frontend","alt-svc":"h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","Etag":"W\/\"10af24-tF23uU9DIoMPnvm2jrbrN4e5JAg\"","x-cloud-trace-context":"104b4a56a5b82510599fa9ab75fcaf0b;o=1","x-powered-by":"Express","Content-Type":"application\/vnd.apple.pkpass; charset=utf-8"}
```

It seems like the response contains the ticket as it has filename etc.

**IOS Side:**

```
var requestData : [String : String]? = [String : String]()
    requestData?.updateValue(postId, forKey: "postId");

    AF.request(URLString, method: .post, parameters: requestData).responseString { response in

        guard let resp = response.data else { return }

        do {
            let pass = try PKPass(data: resp)
            print(pass)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

I get this error when I try to pass the response data in the `PKPass` object

`Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid., NSUnderlyingError=0x600003c91a70 {Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"}}`

The event.pass is the one apple provides and I have added my `passTypeIdentifier` & `teamIdentifier` which seem to be working fine.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479545/swift-pkpass-eror-the-pass-cannot-be-read-because-it-isn-t-valid/61494624#61494624 pass signature is incorrect.

Comment: You can't just simply change the pass.json in the example.  The manifest has to be regenerated and resigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just simply change the pass.json in the example. The manifest has to be regenerated and resigned.

You pass is failing to load because you are using the original signature from the example, but you have changed the data in pass.json which renders the signature invalid.

Comment: How can I regenerate the pass.json?

Comment: The demo comes with a signpass tool (and objective-c) source code.  You will need to edit the manifest file to change the sha1 hash of your new pass.json, then use the signpass tool to generate a signature that uses your certificate and key.